# Display parent navigation link doesn't work

Tags: 2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that has a subsite which then contains a subsite. It looks something like this hierarchically:

- Site Root

  - Subsite A

    - Subsite X (subsite of A)
    - Subsite Y (subsite of A)

The problem is in the navigation up button [image] the link of Subsite A is displayed but cannot be clicked while the rest work fine (Site Root and Subsite X). How do I solve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you navigate to Subsite A directly from browser? You created Subsite A and then created Subsite X and Subsite Y or directly created Subsite X with Subsite A as managed path? I think there is no root site available for Subsite A.

Comment: Thanks Suren. However the entire hierarchy is upgraded from MOSS 2007. I can Navigate to Site Root, as well as Subsite A and Subsite X.Everything in all the sites work fine. The problem is only in the navigation. I think the upgrade process screwed up the navigation controls. Might need to check the layout pages.